# non-finite value supplied by optim when I use estiStAni or fit.StVariogram

Tags: r

I have computed an empirical spatio-temporal variogram and I want to fit it into a model I built using vgmST. However, whenever I call fit.StVariogram I get the error "non-finite value supplied by optim".

I am still a beginner in geostatistics and I don't know if the problem is in the parameters I choose for the model I want to fit, or in choosing the stAni parameter in fit.StVariogram.
I tried calling estiStAni and I still get the same error.

Is there an easier way to automatically estimate the parameters for vgmST? (by parameters I mean the nugget, psill, range and model for both the space and time variograms), or is this error related to something else?